# Prometheus CPU consumption after remote_write is enabled

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have problems figuring out why my Prometheus instance starts to chew a lot of CPU after I enable remote_write feature.

I have deployed a prometheus and grafana from chart kube-prometheus-stack, version 40.1.2. Along with this, we also deployed Grafana Tempo. We opted to add support for service graph, which requires Prometheus remote_write feature to be enabled. After enabling it, the CPU consumption on Prometheus goes from ~30m to ~2700m. Is this expected, and if so, can someone explain why?

On the other hand, if not, can someone point me the direction I should look into?

We tried turning off remote_write on Prometheus, and as soon we disable it, CPU stays pretty low. We would expect that CPU consumption goes up, but not that much.